# Standard way of shortening C++ function signatures

Tags: c++, templates, stl, function-declaration

The templates always get really lengthy when I have certain vector and templated contained objects and the end just looks like a bunch of `> > > > > > >` that hardly helps discern boundaries sometimes, like this:

```
std::vector< std::pair< std::string, std::set< std::string > > >
```

Is there a standard way to reduce the length, or to make the items easily distinguishable?  My actual code is this class declaration.

I have tried shortening the function name and typedef-ing the return value.

```
class Event_Maker
{
    public:

        virtual ~Event_Maker() {};

        // this one                                    *this juts out really far   v
        virtual std::vector< std::unique_ptr< Event > > transfer_events( void ) = 0;
};
```

Comment: like: typedef std::vector< std::unique_ptr< Event > > Event_List; :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a standard way to reduce the length, or to make the items easily distinguishable?

Type aliases using `typedef` can be handy, for example:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<Event> EventPtr;
typedef std::vector<EventPtr> EventVector;
virtual EventVector transfer_events( void ) = 0;
```

Btw, you only need a space between `>>`, you don't need after `<` or before `>`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::set<std::string> > >
```

**UPDATE**

As [@Snowhawk04](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/38656/snowhawk04) and [@mkrieger1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/67888/mkrieger1) pointed out in comments,
with modern compilers you don't need the space between `>>` anymore.
Just make sure to use the right compiler flags,
for example `-std=c++0x` with `g++`.
See more info [about `>>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Right_angle_bracket) and [template aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Template_aliases).

Comment: Don't you nowadays not need the spaces between `> >` anymore? And isn't nowadays `using` preferred over `typedef`?

Comment: `g++` version 4.8.3 needs the spaces. I don't know about `using` over `typedef`.

Comment: C++11 addressed `>>` ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Right_angle_bracket)) and expanded the use of `using` ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Right_angle_bracket)). Make sure you are compiling with C++11 enabled (`-std=c++0x`)

Comment: 2nd link was supposed to be to [template aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Template_aliases).  Right angle brackets have been supported since gcc4.3 and template aliases since gcc4.7. ([GCC Features](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html))

Answer (score 4):

As an additional answer, in C++11 you can use `using` instead of `typedef`, both accomplishes the same thing:

```
//typedef pair<string, set<string>> pairStrSetStr;
using pairStrSetStr = pair<string, set<string>>;
vector<pairStrSetStr> vec;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just create a new line that breaks after the return type. This is what formatting tools like Clang-Format does.

```
struct EventMaker {
    virtual ~EventMaker() {};

    virtual std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Event>> 
    transfer_events() = 0;
};
```

C++11 also introduced the *Trailing-Return-Type*.  Some people swear to hate it outside of its intended uses.

```
struct EventMaker {
    virtual ~EventMaker() {};

    virtual auto transfer_events() 
    -> std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Event>> = 0;
};
```

Unfortunately, we cannot use C++14's *Auto Return Type Deduction* on virtual functions as the return type is part of the contract it has with deriving classes.

Unless you plan on writing multilingual code(i.e. `extern "C"{};`), you can omit `void` parameters on functions that take no arguments, .

Comment: Putting `return_val function( void ) { //stuff }` is really just a habit of mine to make it blatantly obvious :b thanks for the tips though.